# MIPS Nested Procedures

Tags: mips

```
int fact (int n)
{
if (n < 1) return (1);
else return (n * fact(n – 1));
}

fact:
addi $sp, $sp, –8 # adjust stack for 2 items
sw $ra, 4($sp) # save the return address
sw $a0, 0($sp) # save the argument n
slti $t0,$a0,1 # test for n < 1
beq $t0,$zero,L1 # if n >= 1, go to L1
addi $v0,$zero,1 # return 1
addi $sp,$sp,8 # pop 2 items off stack
jr $ra # return to caller

L1: addi $a0,$a0,–1 # n >= 1: argument gets (n – 1)
jal fact # call fact with (n –1)
lw $a0, 0($sp) # return from jal: restore argument n
lw $ra, 4($sp) # restore the return address
addi $sp, $sp, 8 # adjust stack pointer to pop 2 items
mul $v0,$a0,$v0 # return n * fact (n – 1)
jr $ra # return to the caller
```

That's example on the book,I tried to know how it operates but still no idea

1.What happened if I didn't restore return address and argument a0 after L1?

2.What happened if I didn't pop the stack after L1?

3.What happened if I swap restore step and popping step?

Comment: Why not enter the code into a simulator and try out all your "what if"s?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Apparently I can get result if use simulator,but I am wondering the process instead of result

Comment: Use the simulator to observe the process by single-stepping.